# Is ‘broken wing’ an English word?

Tags: word-meaning

I have heard the word "broken wing" used in movies. The meaning is on a website called [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=broken%20wing).

I couldn't find this word in Cambridge or any other trusted dictionary. So I’m a little confused; Is "broken wing" a word or not?

Comment: It's a phrase, not a word, and would normally refer to an injury to a bird. Urban Dictionary seems to imply that some people are using it in a metaphorical sense, but the expression isn't common enough to have made it into the 'official' dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

It's two words, with their usual dictionary meanings.
Urban Dictionary is giving several metaphorical uses of that pair of words together that they consider common enough to be worth reporting.

So, no, it's not a word.

Comment: Thanks, So is the urbandictionary authentic?

Comment: So I could take it two words broken and wing. Now broken could mean hopeless or emotionally down. But how will wing fit in here? I could guess we could say `part` instead of wing, but not sure if that is a correct substitution

Comment: Check out the basic meanings of *broken*, and of *wing*. Now picture a bird trying to fly in that condition, like a human trying to run on a broken leg. That is the basic meaning of *broken wing*. Now you can see the application of that as a metaphor, referring to a person who is emotionally damaged (*broken wing*), so that they can't function normally (*fly* or *run*).

Comment: As to the question about the authenticity of Urban Dictionary, browse there for a while. You'll see that you may be able to get useful information there, but it's not to be taken as a serious reference.

Comment: Remember, anyone can add anything to Urban Dictionary meaning many people add things such as jokes; and it is not moderated much. I would not use it as a legitimate dictionary most of the time.